# Dataframe to Oracle creates table with case sensitive column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Spark: 2.1.1**

I am saving my `dataframe` as an `Oracle` table but the resultant Oracle table has "**case sensitive**" columns.

```
val properties = new java.util.Properties
    properties.setProperty("user", ora_username)
    properties.setProperty("password", ora_pwd)
    properties.setProperty("batchsize", "30000")
    properties.setProperty("driver", db_driver)
```

> ```
> spark.sql("select * from myTable").repartition(50).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url,"myTable_oracle", properties)
> ```

When I see in `Oracle` ,

1. `Select * from myTable_oracle;` => works
2. `Select col1 from myTable_oracle;` => **Doesn't work**
3. `Select "col1" from myTable_oracle;` => works , but is very annoying

**Tried setting below, but still same issue:**

```
spark.sqlContext.sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false")
```

Same code used to work in `Spark 1.6.1` which creates `Oracle` table with case-insensitive columns. But with `Spark 2.1.1` I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 6):

**I found the issue and solution :**
Starting **Spark 2.x** every columnName gets double quoted while creating table and hence the resultant Oracle table's columnNames become case-sensitive when you try to query them via sqlPlus.

**dialect.quoteIdentifier**
[https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L645]

and this **dialect.quoteIdentifier** is Double quotes [**"**]

```
  def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = {
    s""""$colName""""
  }
```

[https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L90]

> Solution : **De-register** existing OracleDialect and **Re-register** while
>   overriding **dialect.quoteIdentifier** along with other necessary stuff needed to work with Oracle Dialect

```
import java.sql.Types
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.{ JdbcDialects, JdbcType, JdbcDialect }


val url= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@HOST:1567/SID"

val dialect = JdbcDialects
JdbcDialects.unregisterDialect(dialect.get(url))

val OracleDialect = new JdbcDialect {
  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:oracle") || url.contains("oracle")

  override def getCatalystType(sqlType: Int, typeName: String, size: Int, md: MetadataBuilder): Option[DataType] = {
    // Handle NUMBER fields that have no precision/scale in special way because JDBC ResultSetMetaData converts this to 0 procision and -127 scale
    if (sqlType == Types.NUMERIC && size == 0) {
      // This is sub-optimal as we have to pick a precision/scale in advance whereas the data in Oracle is allowed 
      //  to have different precision/scale for each value.  This conversion works in our domain for now though we 
      //  need a more durable solution.  Look into changing JDBCRDD (line 406):
      //    FROM:  mutableRow.update(i, Decimal(decimalVal, p, s))
      //    TO:  mutableRow.update(i, Decimal(decimalVal))
      Some(DecimalType(DecimalType.MAX_PRECISION, 10))
    } // Handle Timestamp with timezone (for now we are just converting this to a string with default format)
    //else if (sqlType == -101) {
    // Some(StringType)
    // } 
    else None
  }

  override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = dt match {
    case StringType            => Some(JdbcType("VARCHAR2(2000)", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR))
    case BooleanType           => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(1)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case IntegerType           => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(10)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case LongType              => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(19)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case DoubleType            => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(19,4)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case FloatType             => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(19,4)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case ShortType             => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(5)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case ByteType              => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(3)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case BinaryType            => Some(JdbcType("BLOB", java.sql.Types.BLOB))
    case TimestampType         => Some(JdbcType("DATE", java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP))
    case DateType              => Some(JdbcType("DATE", java.sql.Types.DATE))
    //case DecimalType.Fixed(precision, scale) => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(" + precision + "," + scale + ")", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    //case DecimalType.Unlimited => Some(JdbcType("NUMBER(38,4)", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC))
    case _                     => None
  }

  //Imp from Spark2.0 since otherwise oracle table columns would be case-sensitive
  override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = {
    colName
  }

}

JdbcDialects.registerDialect(OracleDialect)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the fix should take into account the issue that cause the change: [SPARK-16387](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/3b22291b5f0317609cd71ce7af78e4c5063d66e8)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, MetadataBuilder}

object AxOracleDialect extends JdbcDialect {

  def register(): Unit = {
    JdbcDialects.unregisterDialect(OracleDialect)
    JdbcDialects.registerDialect(this)
  }

  private val reservedWordsAndKeywords = Set(
    "ACCESS", "ACCOUNT", "ACTIVATE", "ADD", "ADMIN", "ADVISE", "AFTER", "ALL", "ALL_ROWS",
    "ALLOCATE", "ALTER", "ANALYZE", "AND", "ANY", "ARCHIVE", "ARCHIVELOG", "ARRAY", "AS",
    "ASC", "AT", "AUDIT", "AUTHENTICATED", "AUTHORIZATION", "AUTOEXTEND", "AUTOMATIC", "BACKUP", "BECOME",
    "BEFORE", "BEGIN", "BETWEEN", "BFILE", "BITMAP", "BLOB", "BLOCK", "BODY", "BY",
    "CACHE", "CACHE_INSTANCES", "CANCEL", "CASCADE", "CAST", "CFILE", "CHAINED", "CHANGE", "CHAR",
    "CHAR_CS", "CHARACTER", "CHECK", "CHECKPOINT", "CHOOSE", "CHUNK", "CLEAR", "CLOB", "CLONE",
    "CLOSE", "CLOSE_CACHED_OPEN_CURSORS", "CLUSTER", "COALESCE", "COLUMN", "COLUMNS", "COMMENT", "COMMIT", "COMMITTED",
    "COMPATIBILITY", "COMPILE", "COMPLETE", "COMPOSITE_LIMIT", "COMPRESS", "COMPUTE", "CONNECT", "CONNECT_TIME", "CONSTRAINT",
    "CONSTRAINTS", "CONTENTS", "CONTINUE", "CONTROLFILE", "CONVERT", "COST", "CPU_PER_CALL", "CPU_PER_SESSION", "CREATE",
    "CURRENT", "CURRENT_SCHEMA", "CURREN_USER", "CURSOR", "CYCLE,DANGLING", "DATABASE", "DATAFILE", "DATAFILES", "DATAOBJNO",
    "DATE", "DBA", "DBHIGH", "DBLOW", "DBMAC", "DEALLOCATE", "DEBUG", "DEC", "DECIMAL",
    "DECLARE", "DEFAULT", "DEFERRABLE", "DEFERRED", "DEGREE", "DELETE", "DEREF", "DESC", "DIRECTORY",
    "DISABLE", "DISCONNECT", "DISMOUNT", "DISTINCT", "DISTRIBUTED", "DML", "DOUBLE", "DROP", "DUMP",
    "EACH", "ELSE", "ENABLE", "END", "ENFORCE", "ENTRY", "ESCAPE", "EXCEPT", "EXCEPTIONS", "EXCHANGE",
    "EXCLUDING", "EXCLUSIVE", "EXECUTE", "EXISTS", "EXPIRE", "EXPLAIN", "EXTENT", "EXTENTS", "EXTERNALLY",
    "FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS", "FALSE", "FAST", "FILE", "FIRST_ROWS", "FLAGGER", "FLOAT", "FLOB", "FLUSH",
    "FOR", "FORCE", "FOREIGN", "FREELIST", "FREELISTS", "FROM", "FULL", "FUNCTION", "GLOBAL",
    "GLOBALLY", "GLOBAL_NAME", "GRANT", "GROUP", "GROUPS", "HASH", "HASHKEYS", "HAVING", "HEADER", "HEAP",
    "IDENTIFIED", "IDGENERATORS", "IDLE_TIME", "IF", "IMMEDIATE", "IN", "INCLUDING", "INCREMENT", "INDEX", "INDEXED",
    "INDEXES", "INDICATOR", "IND_PARTITION", "INITIAL", "INITIALLY", "INITRANS", "INSERT", "INSTANCE", "INSTANCES", "INSTEAD",
    "INT", "INTEGER", "INTERMEDIATE", "INTERSECT", "INTO", "IS", "ISOLATION", "ISOLATION_LEVEL", "KEEP", "KEY", "KILL", "LABEL",
    "LAYER", "LESS", "LEVEL", "LIBRARY", "LIKE", "LIMIT", "LINK", "LIST", "LOB", "LOCAL", "LOCK", "LOCKED", "LOG", "LOGFILE",
    "LOGGING", "LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL", "LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION", "LONG", "MANAGE", "MASTER", "MAX", "MAXARCHLOGS",
    "MAXDATAFILES", "MAXEXTENTS", "MAXINSTANCES", "MAXLOGFILES", "MAXLOGHISTORY", "MAXLOGMEMBERS", "MAXSIZE", "MAXTRANS",
    "MAXVALUE", "MIN", "MEMBER", "MINIMUM", "MINEXTENTS", "MINUS", "MINVALUE", "MLSLABEL", "MLS_LABEL_FORMAT", "MODE", "MODIFY",
    "MOUNT", "MOVE", "MTS_DISPATCHERS", "MULTISET", "NATIONAL", "NCHAR", "NCHAR_CS", "NCLOB", "NEEDED", "NESTED", "NETWORK",
    "NEW", "NEXT", "NOARCHIVELOG", "NOAUDIT", "NOCACHE", "NOCOMPRESS", "NOCYCLE", "NOFORCE", "NOLOGGING", "NOMAXVALUE", "NOMINVALUE",
    "NONE", "NOORDER", "NOOVERRIDE", "NOPARALLEL", "NOPARALLEL", "NOREVERSE", "NORMAL", "NOSORT", "NOT", "NOTHING", "NOWAIT", "NULL",
    "NUMBER", "NUMERIC", "NVARCHAR2", "OBJECT", "OBJNO", "OBJNO_REUSE", "OF", "OFF", "OFFLINE", "OID", "OIDINDEX", "OLD", "ON",
    "ONLINE", "ONLY", "OPCODE", "OPEN", "OPTIMAL", "OPTIMIZER_GOAL", "OPTION", "OR", "ORDER", "ORGANIZATION", "OSLABEL", "OVERFLOW",
    "OWN", "PACKAGE", "PARALLEL", "PARTITION", "PASSWORD", "PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME", "PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME", "PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME",
    "PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX", "PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME", "PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION", "PCTFREE", "PCTINCREASE", "PCTTHRESHOLD", "PCTUSED",
    "PCTVERSION", "PERCENT", "PERMANENT", "PLAN", "PLSQL_DEBUG", "POST_TRANSACTION", "PRECISION", "PRESERVE", "PRIMARY", "PRIOR",
    "PRIVATE", "PRIVATE_SGA", "PRIVILEGE", "PRIVILEGES", "PROCEDURE", "PROFILE", "PUBLIC", "PURGE", "QUEUE", "QUOTA", "RANGE",
    "RAW", "RBA", "READ", "READUP", "REAL", "REBUILD", "RECOVER", "RECOVERABLE", "RECOVERY", "REF", "REFERENCES", "REFERENCING",
    "REFRESH", "RENAME", "REPLACE", "RESET", "RESETLOGS", "RESIZE", "RESOURCE", "RESTRICTED", "RETURN", "RETURNING", "REUSE",
    "REVERSE", "REVOKE", "ROLE", "ROLES", "ROLLBACK", "ROW", "ROWID", "ROWNUM", "ROWS", "RULE", "SAMPLE", "SAVEPOINT", "SB4",
    "SCAN_INSTANCES", "SCHEMA", "SCN", "SCOPE", "SD_ALL", "SD_INHIBIT", "SD_SHOW", "SEGMENT", "SEG_BLOCK", "SEG_FILE", "SELECT",
    "SEQUENCE", "SERIALIZABLE", "SESSION", "SESSION_CACHED_CURSORS", "SESSIONS_PER_USER", "SET", "SHARE", "SHARED", "SHARED_POOL",
    "SHRINK", "SIZE", "SKIP", "SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES", "SMALLINT", "SNAPSHOT", "SOME", "SORT", "SPECIFICATION", "SPLIT",
    "SQL_TRACE", "STANDBY", "START", "STATEMENT_ID", "STATISTICS", "STOP", "STORAGE", "STORE", "STRUCTURE", "SUCCESSFUL",
    "SWITCH", "SYS_OP_ENFORCE_NOT_NULL$", "SYS_OP_NTCIMG$", "SYNONYM", "SYSDATE", "SYSDBA", "SYSOPER", "SYSTEM", "TABLE",
    "TABLES", "TABLESPACE", "TABLESPACE_NO", "TABNO", "TEMPORARY", "THAN", "THE", "THEN", "THREAD", "TIMESTAMP", "TIME", "TO",
    "TOPLEVEL", "TRACE", "TRACING", "TRANSACTION", "TRANSITIONAL", "TRIGGER", "TRIGGERS", "TRUE", "TRUNCATE", "TX", "TYPE", "UB2",
    "UBA", "UID", "UNARCHIVED", "UNDO", "UNION", "UNIQUE", "UNLIMITED", "UNLOCK", "UNRECOVERABLE", "UNTIL", "UNUSABLE", "UNUSED",
    "UPDATABLE", "UPDATE", "USAGE", "USE", "USER", "USING", "VALIDATE", "VALIDATION", "VALUE", "VALUES", "VARCHAR", "VARCHAR2",
    "VARYING", "VIEW", "WHEN", "WHENEVER", "WHERE", "WITH", "WITHOUT", "WORK", "WRITE", "WRITEDOWN", "WRITEUP", "XID", "YEAR",
    "ZONE"
  )

  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = OracleDialect.canHandle(url)

  override def getCatalystType(sqlType: Int, typeName: String, size: Int, md: MetadataBuilder): Option[DataType] =
    OracleDialect.getCatalystType(sqlType, typeName, size, md)

  override def getJDBCType(dt: DataType): Option[JdbcType] = OracleDialect.getJDBCType(dt)

  override def compileValue(value: Any): Any = OracleDialect.compileValue(value)

  override def isCascadingTruncateTable(): Option[Boolean] = OracleDialect.isCascadingTruncateTable()

  override def getTruncateQuery(table: String, cascade: Option[Boolean] = isCascadingTruncateTable()): String = OracleDialect.getTruncateQuery(table, cascade)

  override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String =
    if (reservedWordsAndKeywords.contains(colName.toUpperCase)) super.quoteIdentifier(colName)
    else colName
}
```